# How to make Entity Framework execute asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have problem with asynchronous controller in ASP.Net MVC 5 application.
I'm using Entity Framework 6 Code First approach.

I have a method

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    using(var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        var eventsTask = context.Events
            .Where(e => e.Enable)
            .ToListAsync();

        var countTask = context.Users
            .CountAsync();

        await Task.WhenAll(eventsTask, countTask);
        return View(new ViewModel()
        {
            Events = eventsTask.Result, 
            Count = countTask.Result
        });
    }
}
```

I have two asyncronous methods here. I have measured each of them separately via MiniProfiler. They takes ~85 ms.

But in my method I run them using Task.WhenAll(). I believe it executes Db queries asynchronously and should take about ~85-90 ms for both. But it takes ~170-180. So I have got asynchronous methods run synchronously (following each other).

I think it is because of context. I have a test, when I remove context queries and call many api methods using HttpClient. It takes time equals to longer of them (3 api calling, ~500 ms each of them. Totally method takes ~600 ms). I believe that It is possible to execute EF methods asynchronously.

Does anyone know the solution

Comment: Does EF even support parallel operations? Probably it just serializes them.

Comment: Try using different contexts for each task and post the timing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mutil async entity framework 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628792/mutil-async-entity-framework-6)

Comment: I have read this post. I tried different context, but have got the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This shouldn't even work actually, but throw an exception instead. I'm guessing the first query completes before the second one even starts.

[EF6 doesn't support multiple async operations on the same context.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702183/does-entity-framework-support-parallel-async-queries)

Either `await` each query (so they won't run concurrently), or use a different context for each query.

Comment: It works fine, without any . But also I have tried to use different context I had the same result.

Comment: @GFoley83 Not sure why you linked this, but the described answer won't work

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The reason is a MiniProfiler.EF6. 
1) To measure my sql question I use MiniProfiler.EF6. This framework avoid concurrent sql queries even I use different EF DBContext.

2) I disable MiniProfile.EF6 and run my application. I have got an exception about that ken2k mentioned. To avoid this exception I follow this answer
[EF6 doesn't support multiple async operations on the same context.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702183/does-entity-framework-support-parallel-async-queries)

3) I measure Dapper and concurrent SQL queries. I have used a single SQLConnection for asyncronous queries in my tests. I have had the results:

a) if i use SqlConnection for Dapper then queries execute
    asynchronous (parallel)

b) if i use ProfiledDbConnection from
    MiniProfiler then Dapper execute queries follow each others (not
    parallel)