# Task and multiple operations on Context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I have this code to retrieve data from my database:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Member>> GetAllMembersAsync()
{
    var members = Repository.GetAll<Member>();

    return await Task.Run(() => members.ToListAsync());
}
```

For an unknown reason (maybe a bug?), I have to use `Task.Run` in order to make this work (the repository just returns a `DbSet<Member>`. If I don't do this, my UI hangs forever.

The problem is that I can't do 2 database operations at the same time this way. If I do this, I get this error:

```
A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
```

As you see, I'm already using `await`.

Is there any way to solve this so I can actually do 2 database operations at the same time and so they run in order?

EDIT:
Code that calls this:

```
private async void LoadMembers()
{
    try
    {
        var members = await MemberService.GetAllMembersAsync();

        Members = new ObservableCollection<Member>(members);
    }
    catch (EntityException)
    {
        // connection lost?
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that is calling your `GetAllMembersAsync()` method?

Comment: How using a `.ContinueWith` for the second async call? You'd have to kick off another task in the continuation, but at least these tasks will be daisy-chained. So many ways to skin this cat, though...

Comment: The problem is I don't know what the next async call is - the user could decide to do multiple things. It could be retrieiving all members again, or doing something completely different;

Comment: Then keep the reference to the last task being run, and if the user keeps appending data fetch ops, add these in as continuations. Just don't throw away your reference to the last task run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mutil async entity framework 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628792/mutil-async-entity-framework-6)

Comment: What exactly is the second operation because your code shows only one. Getting all members.

Comment: The second operation in this case is getting all members 2 times. But it could be something completely different..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. As the error suggests you can't have 2 concurrent EF operations at the same time. Here's a more thorough answer about that: [Does Entity Framework support parallel async queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24702369/885318)

On top of that, you don't need to use `Task.Run` to solve what seems to be a deadlock issue. Simply use `ConfigureAwait` to make sure the `async` operation doesn't need the UI `SynchronizationContext` to complete on. (also, make sure you don't block on `async` code with `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result`):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Member>> GetAllMembersAsync()
{
    return await Repository.GetAll<Member>().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private async void LoadMembers()
{
    try
    {
        var members = await MemberService.GetAllMembersAsync();
        Members = new ObservableCollection<Member>(members);
    }
    catch (EntityException)
    {
        // connection lost?
    }
}
```

Comment: So what about this: I create a Singleton called SIngleTask to use for database operations. This Singleton makes sure only one Task is active. If not, it uses ContinueWith. 

Is this a good option?

Comment: @Bv202 There are simpler ways to serialize `async` operations. You can simply use a `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` configured with 1.

Comment: I'd solve the deadlock by removing the wait that surely is hidden somewhere. ConfigureAwait(false) is the wrong treatment.

Comment: @Bv202 @usr, you should do both. And that's unrelated to the concurrent  `async` EF operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip of using SemaphoreSlim! That seems to do exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are in a deadlock situation because you are not using configureawait(true) properly.
You can do

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Member>> GetAllMembersAsync()
{
   var members = Repository.GetAll<Member>();

   return await Task.Run(() => members.ToListAsync());
}

private async void LoadMembers()
{
   try
   {
       var members = await MemberService.GetAllMembersAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);

       Members = new ObservableCollection<Member>(members);
   }
   catch (EntityException)
   {
    // connection lost?
   }

}
```

after the operation is complete, and if executed from the GUI thread, the GUI thread will resume.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to do the trick! Why do I need to use this extra method? Shouldn't that be the default behavior?

Comment: var members = await MemberService.GetAllMembersAsync().ConfigureAwait(true); is more correct. The reason is that your observablecollection is next in line and is used in binding operations on the GUI thread. That in combination with var list = await members.ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false) also works.
I like to explicitely do these calls to configureawait even when not needed, there is a default, because it shows intent. If this solves your problem please mark as answer ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, it makes my UI hang while retrieving the data... :(

Comment: The answer is nice, but is not for the question that was asked. The question was how to run multiple database operations on the same context at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I'm still getting the same error: operation on context already running...

Comment: If that is the question then the answer is that it is impossible using the same context. I thought the idea of the requester was to decouple the from the GUI thread. But multiple queries have the be executed one by one, if using the same context.

Comment: So I'll have to create a new context for EVERY database operation?

Comment: Only if you want to run them in parallel.

Comment: My situation: the user clicks on a menu item, new data is loaded. The user then clicks on another menu item and new data is loaded, while the previous load may not be completed. How to implement this the best way?

Comment: You would need to cancel the previous query before attempting the new one. Or use a new context with each click. Cancelling can be done using a CancellationSource and token. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I can't just cancel these queries - now it's just loading, but it could also be adding, deleting,...

Creating a new context every time seems to slow down the applicatio a LOT...