# Entity framework async issues context or query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I have async issue with my below query. I have singleton context and i am trying to execute below query:

```
var query = await (from parent in Context.ParentTable
                   join child in Context.ChildTable
                   on parent.ID equals child.ID
                   into allResult
                   from ResultValue in allResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   where ResultValue.TenantId == tenantId
                   select new Result
                   {
                      Code = parent.Code,
                      Type = parent.Type,
                      ID = ResultValue == null ? 0 : ResultValue.Id
                   }).ToListAsync();
```

My singleton context looks like this:

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    private readonly IConfigurationContextFactory configurationContextFactory;

    private IConfigurationContext context;

    protected IConfigurationContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            return context ?? (context = configurationContextFactory.Context);
        }
    }

    public BaseRepository(IConfigurationContextFactory configurationContextFactory)
    {
        this.configurationContextFactory = configurationContextFactory;
    }
}
```

The configuration context factory returns Context like this:

```
private ConfigurationContext Get()
{
    logger.WriteEntrySync(LogLevel.Information,
                          null != context ? "Config Context: Using existing context." : "Config Context: Wiil create new context.");
    return context ?? (context = new ConfigurationContext(connectionString));
}
```

In this i get intermittent issue with following error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous
>   asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

Comment: EF context as a singleton is a big no-no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-async in Entity Framework 6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628792/multi-async-in-entity-framework-6)

Answer (score 22):

> I have singleton context

This is your problem. `DbContext` isn't thread-safe, and is designed to execute one query at a time. Since you're sharing your `DbContext`, you're probably attempting to invoke another query concurrently, which isn't "legal" in `DbContext` terms.

You can even see it in the [remarks of `ToListAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/0f8a94107fc6f89ef0bb529a3a56f148bfcc8087/src/EntityFramework.Core/Extensions/EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.cs):

> Multiple active operations on the same context
>   instance are not supported.  Use 'await' to ensure that any
>   asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method
>   on this context.

What you *should* do is not re-use your context with a global singleton, by create a new context each time you want to query your database.

**Edit:**

Instead of getting a single `Context` via your factory method, simply allocate a new one for every query:

```
using (var context = new ConfigurationContext(connectionString))
{
    var query = await (from feature in context.Features
                join featureFlag in context.FeatureFlags
                on feature.FeatureId equals featureFlag.FeatureId
                into allFeatures
                from featureFlagValue in allFeatures.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where featureFlagValue.TenantId == tenantId
                select new BusinessEntities.FeatureFlag
                {
                   Code = feature.Code,
                   Type = feature.Type,
                   FeatureFlagId = featureFlagValue == null ? 0 : featureFlagValue.FeatureFlagId
                }).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @yuval.
I have updated my question. 
i am not sure how should i create new instance of context in linq join query. Or whole linq join query will be on single context?
Bit confused still

Comment: @Rusty Edited my answer with an example.

Comment: I am suppose to use context factory, i was using "using" statement before. 
So is there a way to use context factory but it should return a new context by a property?

Comment: @Rusty You can simply return a fresh instance each time you invoke the factory method, but i don't really see the point in that.

Comment: You need a new instance for each unit of work, not each time you want to query. @Rusty, you can change your factory property to a method nammed CreateContext

Comment: @Guillaume can you provide me some reference, how to do that

Answer (score 10):

A `DbContext` should live for one business transaction (unit of work), no more no less.
A business transaction is usually a request, a page or a form. DbContext is not thread safe, it keeps an internal entity cache and tracks changes so you cannot share it accros multiple request.

**You really need to read Entity Framework documentation : [Working with DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx).**

I wouldn't create an instance per repository as a business transaction can manipulate several repositories.

You can inject the context in your repository :

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    private IConfigurationContext context;
    public BaseRepository(IConfigurationContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
    //...
}
```

Change your factory so it creates an instance each time :

```
public interface IConfigurationContextFactory
{
    IConfigurationContext CreateContext();
}

// ...
public ConfigurationContext CreateContext()
{
    return new ConfigurationContext(connectionString);
}
```

Then configure your dependency resolver to inject a `IConfigurationContext` per unit of work. Let's say you are working on an ASP.NET application using unity.

```
container.RegisterType<IConfigurationContext>(
    //Instance per http request (unit of work)
    new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
    //Create using factory
    new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<IConfigurationContextFactory>.CreateContext()));
```

Don't forget to call `SaveChangesAsync` at the end of your business transaction when needed : operation succeeded and modifications need to be persisted.