# EF Core multiple HTTP requests throws an error

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I cannot seem to find an answer to this question.

So in the frontend when the user loads a page we call an API for each item on that page (10 items). So that equals 10 API calls.

Most of the calls work but there are always a few that fail when trying to query the database resulting in the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members
>   are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Now I understand that Entity Framework is not thread safe but I am unsure how to get around this error.

Everywhere where I am using a DBContext it is always injected in using the built in .net core Ioc container.

Here is the DI setup

```
services.AddScoped<IOmbiContext, OmbiContext>();
services.AddTransient<ISettingsRepository, SettingsJsonRepository>();
```

All of my repositories are setup in a `Transient` scope with the Context as `Scoped` according to this article:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/entity-framework-6

Now I have tried changing the context to `Transient` and it still happens.

How can I avoid this?

**More Information**

The API Method:

```
[HttpGet("movie/info/{theMovieDbId}")]
public async Task<SearchMovieViewModel> GetExtraMovieInfo(int theMovieDbId)
{
    return await MovieEngine.LookupImdbInformation(theMovieDbId);
}
```

Which eventually calls the following where the exception is being thrown:

```
public async Task<RuleResult> Execute(SearchViewModel obj)
{
    var item = await PlexContentRepository.Get(obj.CustomId); <-- Here
    if (item != null)
    {
        obj.Available = true;
        obj.PlexUrl = item.Url;
        obj.Quality = item.Quality;
    }
    return Success();
}
```

**PlexContentRepository**

```
public PlexContentRepository(IOmbiContext db)
{
    Db = db;
}

private IOmbiContext Db { get; }
public async Task<PlexContent> Get(string providerId)
{
   return await Db.PlexContent.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ProviderId == providerId); <-- Here
}
```

Comment: Does this apply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628792/multi-async-in-entity-framework-6#20635076

Comment: @Nkosi No, everything is fully asynchronous all the way down the stack using the `async` and `await` keywords.

Comment: Are you able to show the API being called that throws the error

Comment: @Nkosi There is quite a lot of code, but i've updated my question to include the important bits. The software is Open Source so I can include a link to the Github project if anyone will find that useful

Comment: Already looking at the repo. :)

Comment: So far from my initial review of the code it may be related to sqlite. That is my initial assessment. Will follow up if confirmed.

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you very much for investigating!

Comment: How are the `IRules<SearchViewModel>` added to the object graph. Can't seem to find how they get into the container

Comment: I believe the issue is related to the lifetime scope of the objects in use.

Comment: @Nkosi But i've tried Transient and Scoped...

Comment: @JamieRees I have same problem ,for god's sake, do you have any success after 2 month with this problem ?
It drives me crazy...

Comment: @paradise_human Yes I did fix it, but I cannot remember how... I did upgrade to .Net Core 2.0. You can take a look at the commits around this time if you want: https://github.com/tidusjar/Ombi/commits/DotNetCore

Comment: @JamieRees I used .net core 2 , too . as I investigate your code my pattern is like you. I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: @JamieRees The Github repro is down? I have the same issue with Core 2.0, shame that you don't remember how it was solved :(.

Comment: @LarsThorén That branch has been deleted so just look at https://github.com/tidusjar/Ombi/

Answer (score -2):

If you use Entity Framework Core usually you do not need to add your Database Context as an additional service

I recommend to setup your DbContext in the `Startup.cs` as following:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<OmbiContext>();
```

Followed by a Controller class for your API calls taking the DBContext as constructor parameter.

```
public class ApiController : Controller
{
    protected OmbiContext ctx;
    public ApiController(OmbiContext dbctx)
    {
        ctx = dbctx;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> yourAsyncAction()
    {
        // access ctx here
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. The Context has also been injected in to assist with Unit Testing, following the Inversion of control responsibility

Comment: IMO - The questioner is building a second service which may cause the error mentioned